redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush is slow
I have a java interface,code is
1. check_param..
2. check_quota: the step will operate redis
3. construct data..
4. push data to queue: redisTemplate.opsForList().rightPush(FAVORITES_RECORD_BLOCKING_QUEUE_KEY, JSON.toJSONString(favorite));

when i reboot my program, in 4th step ,it will consumed above 200ms, and after this,just consumed 3-5ms ,i want to know why.
First I think maybe program get redis connect,so consumed so much time,but in 2th step,it executed :redisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, count,30,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
i have no idea ,please help me
